# I have issue in onclick and href in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have link as follows:

```
<a onclick=delete() href=".$this->action('delete', $data['status_id']).">Delete</a>
```

the javascript code as follows:

```
function delete() {
    if (confirm('<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>')){
         return true;
    }
}
```

the confirmation message shown, if i cancel message the href link target executes. How
to stay it if user cancel confirmation means?

Comment: @alKid More over same but, they using jquery In this problem he asked for pure javascript.

Answer (score 4):

you have to return the result in onclick (and use quotes!)

```
<a onclick="return delete()" 
   href=".$this->action('delete', $data['status_id']).">Delete</a>
```

and remember to return false if the user does not confirm, this is a small change:

```
function delete() {
    return confirm('<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`function delete() {`

`return confirm("<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>");`

`}`

If user will press a cancel button `confirm` will return `false`.
In DOM event handlers `return false` is the same than prevent default(browser) behavior.

Comment: no its execute ... not working

Comment: add return in onclick attribute `<a onclick="return delete()"...`

Answer (score 2):

You need to reverse your logic to prevent the click, rather than allow it:

```
function delete() {
    if (!confirm('<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>')){
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think my question not clear to you, even my ok or cancle the confirmation its execute... anyway thanks i got it...

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
function delete(e) {
    if (confirm('<?php echo $delConfirmJS ?>')){
         return true;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

P.S. and please put your attributes values in quotes, i.e. `onclick=delete()` should be `onclick="delete()"`.